# Координати окна

Tags: python, pygame

Доброго дня я не знаю как при создании окна `screen_menu = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))`
задать координаты?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста пояснить что за координаты. В текущем виде вопрос непонятен. Его необходимо править

Comment: Оно создается почти за экраном, а я хочу, чтобы было по середине.

Comment: к сожалению, никак, в ```pygame``` этого сделать нельзя, но можно при создании окна указывать как аргумент параметр ```pygame.FULLSCREEN``` чтобы окно открывалось на весь экран, и за экраном ничего не было бы)

Comment: Я делаю меню воно має бути в три раза меншим чим окно игри можна както уменшить його?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какие координаты? Просто поменяй 600, 400 на то значение, которое нужно. В комментариях увидел, что окно должно быть в 3 раза меньше, за окно игры. Раздели значения главного окна на 3 и поставь значения в новое окно. Например c1, c2 - значения первого окна

```
mainwindow = pygame.display.set_mode((c1, c2))
#Теперь второе
c3 = c1//3
c4 = c2//3
screen_menu = pygame.display.set_mode((c3, c4))
```

Если я правильно понял задание, то все должно быть нормально